# How to hide an exposed port of a Kubenetes LoadBalancer Service?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have a LoadBalancer service and 6009 and 80 ports are exposed to public.

following is the yml

```
image:
  repository: ms-test
  pullPolicy: Always

service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
    - port: 6009
      targetPort: 6009
      protocol: TCP
      name: http-6009

network_policy:
  enabled: true
  spec:
    policyTypes:
      - Ingress
    ingress:
      - ports:
        - port: 80
          protocol: 
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: 10m
    memory: 150Mi
```

i want to hide the 80 port because it will be used by internal services.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the part with port `80`:

```yaml
image:
  repository: ms-test
  pullPolicy: Always

service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - port: 6009
      targetPort: 6009
      protocol: TCP
      name: http-6009

network_policy:
  enabled: false

resources:
  requests:
    cpu: 10m
    memory: 150Mi
```

> make sure that `network_policy` is set as you want, I don't know if and how you want to expose that `6009` port

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that this solution will work without having another service of type `ClusterIP` which is not present here (based on `i want to hide the 80 port because it will be used by internal services.`).

Comment: Creating a second internal-only Service is fine.

Comment: @DavidMaze how to do that?

Comment: @nipunajayawardana I think you should be able to google "how to create a service in Kubernetes", also please let me know if your issue (hiding port `80`) is resolved with my suggestion

Comment: @wiktor your suggestion doesn't resolve my issue. you have removed the port 80. I want the port 80 but it shouldn't be exposed to the public.

Comment: @nipunajayawardana then the question was wrongly asked ("i want to hide the 80 port"). You need to switch from `LoadBalancer` to `ClusterIP`